# Preview very slow on OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, freeze, osx-yosemite, preview.app

I have a MacBook Pro from 2011 with 4GB RAM and an i5, running **OSX Yosemite 10.10.5**.
Since recently, Preview is ridiculously slow, taking long to start up, but **periodically freezing** for about 5-10 seconds (pdfs, pngs, it doesn't matter...).
I have checked Activity Monitor and RAM and CPU are free. Preview is not taking any significant load, but periodically says **'not responding'**.

I'm not entirely sure, but I think it's since the last small update. It ran fluently on Yosemite before.
Any ideas on how to fix something like this?